# Repeating a regexextract condition

Tags: google-sheets

In sheets, say I have this:

| Word | Onset |
| --- | --- |
| bɐ.ˈɾi.ɕiɾ |  |
| ˈbɑː.tiɾ |  |
| ˌbɛs.bɛ.ˈtɾɑɪ̯.ɕe |  |

My regexextract in Onset looks like this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A109,"[\.ʔ]ˈ?ˌ?([^ɐɛiouɪɑʊɔ]+)[ɐɛiouɪɑʊɔ]")
```

Aka: Extract the non-vowels that are preceded by a . (and an optional ˈ or ˌ) and followed by vowels.

I want to extract all instances within a word--this catches only the t in ˈbɑː.**t**iɾ and throws a #N/A with the others, and if I add another one:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A109,"[\.ʔ]ˈ?ˌ?([^ɐɛiouɪɑʊɔ]+)[ɐɛiouɪɑʊɔ]+[\.ʔ]ˈ?ˌ?([^ɐɛiouɪɑʊɔ]+)[ɐɛiouɪɑʊɔ]+")
```

This will only catch the ɾ and ɕ within bɐ.ˈ**ɾ**i.**ɕ**iɾ but throw a #N/A for the rest.

I've tried clustering and adding a plus like so:
=REGEXEXTRACT(A99,"([.ʔ]ˈ?ˌ?([^ɐɛiouɪɑʊɔ]+)[ɐɛiouɪɑʊɔ])+")

The the result I get is this:

| Word | Onset |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bɐ.ˈɾi.ɕiɾ | .ɕi | ɕ |

Which, uh, not what I wanted.

(and I tried the {A, B} thing, and adding the second set with a question mark...)

So what I'm looking for is

| Word | Onset |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bɐ.ˈɾi.ɕiɾ | ɾ | ɕ |  |
| ˈbɑː.tiɾ | t |  |  |
| ˌbɛs.bɛ.ˈtɾɑɪ̯.ɕe | b | tr | ɕ |

Or maybe

| Word | Onset |
| --- | --- |
| bɐ.ˈɾi.ɕiɾ | ɾ, ɕ |
| ˈbɑː.tiɾ | t |
| ˌbɛs.bɛ.ˈtɾɑɪ̯.ɕe | b, tɾ, ɕ |

I've tried (Oh, my god, have I tried) to look for a solution, but ultimately I don't understand regex well enough, to begin with, to properly apply the suggested solutions I've found... I'm hoping someone will bend this out of iron rail for me.

Comment: As noted by [TheMaster in their answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/173451) you don't list `e`  as a vowel in your list of vowels `[ɐɛiouɪɑʊɔ]` but in your desired outcome you show `ɕ` in the third row of the onset column which is only possible if `e` is part of the vowel list. Can you please [edit] your question to clarify? ie.  add `e` as a vowel if it was an oversight, or remove `ɕ` from the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Formula in `B2`

##### Single Row, Multiple Formulas

```
=JOIN(", ", 
   REGEXEXTRACT(A2, 
     REGEXREPLACE(A2,
       "(\.[ˌˈ]?)([^ɐɛiouɪɑʊɔ])", "$1($2)")))
```

##### Single Formula, Multiple Rows

```
=MAP(TOCOL(A2:A,1), LAMBDA(r, 
  JOIN(", ", 
    REGEXEXTRACT(r,
      REGEXREPLACE(r,"(\.[ˌˈ]?)([^ɐɛiouɪɑʊɔ])", "$1($2)")))))
```

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Strings** | **Results** |
| 2 | bɐ.ˈɾi.ɕiɾ | ɾ, ɕ |
| 3 | ˈbɑː.tiɾ | t |
| 4 | ˌbɛs.bɛ.ˈtɾɑɪ̯.ɕe | b, t, ɕ |

## Explanation

- REGEXREPLACE captures two groups `$1` and `$2`:

  1. `$1` is a `.` followed by zero or one characters from `[ˌˈ]` that precede `$2`
  2. `$2` is any character that follows `$1` that is not in the exclusion list `[^ɐɛiouɪɑʊɔ]`.
  3. The replacement expression `$1($2)` creates a string.
     For example, if the original text is `ˌbɛs.bɛ.ˈtɾɑɪ̯.ɕe` then it will become `ˌbɛs.(b)ɛ.ˈ(t)ɾɑɪ̯.(ɕ)e`
- REGEXTRACT uses the result from the previous step as a regular expression.  So if the previous result was `ˌbɛs.(b)ɛ.ˈ(t)ɾɑɪ̯.(ɕ)e` it returns `btɕ`
- JOIN adds a comma followed by a space as the delimiter making the final result `b, t, ɕ` as in `B4` above.

Answer (score 1):

> This will only catch the ɾ and ɕ within bɐ.ˈɾi.ɕiɾ but throw a #N/A for the rest.

Repeating the regular expressions can work. But since we need to match the entire expression, we need to know the exact number of times `.[Non-vowel][vowel]` is present and therefore the number of times the regex needs to be repeated.   Here, I use `REDUCE` to loop over a `SEQUENCE` of 10 numbers(in reverse),  and each number in the sequence is used to `REP`ea`T` the regular expressions. `IF` it(`10`) `ERROR`s out, we try the next number of repetition(`9`), if not we keep the current one. We do this in a loop and therefore keep the maximum number that doesn't error.

```
=REDUCE(
  NA(),
  SEQUENCE(10,1,10,-1),
  LAMBDA(
    a,c, 
    IFERROR(
     a,
     REGEXEXTRACT(A2,REPT("\.\ˈ?([^ɐɛiouɪɑʊɔ]+)[ɐɛiouɪɑʊɔ]+.*?",c)))
  )
)
```

| Word | Onset | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bɐ.ˈɾi.ɕiɾ | ɾ | ɕ |
| ˈbɑː.tiɾ | t |  |
| ˌbɛs.bɛ.ˈtɾɑɪ̯.ɕe | b | tɾ |

Note that `e` in `ˌbɛs.bɛ.ˈtɾɑɪ̯.ɕe` is not a vowel( in list `[ɐɛiouɪɑʊɔ]`) and therefore, `ɕ` is not extracted.